# Hosting a domain/subdomain on shared hosting and cloud simultaneously

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud, hosting, digital-ocean

I'm planning to create a live interactive classroom application. It will contain two parts. One will be the live teaching tool which will require good server specifications and the other will just be a static website with some recorded video lectures.

I want to host the static website on a shared hosting server and the live teaching tool on a cloud like aws or digital ocean. The point of concern here is that I want to keep my service virtually integrated and therefore would like to host the entire website on the same domain name.

I don't feel like it is possible on the very first thought, but is there any way to make it work? Does hosting cloud service on a subdomain help me achieve my goal?

The reason I'm stressing on hosting on shared hosting platform is because I have already purchased a decent shared hosting service and would like to use it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible through a CDN where you can add multiple origin /source and choose to route the traffic based on request parameters, e.g. if request path starts with /static the request will be served through to static website. Everything else will be served through dynamic backend.

AWS has cloudfront whereas GCP has cloud CDN. Either of them can handle your requirements without a problem.

Here's how you do this in AWS CloudFront:

1. You first create a distribution in CDN
2. You point your domain to distribution (through CNAME or ALIAS record)
3. Add default origin to go to your dynamic site
4. Specify path for /static origin.

It sounds like you are trying to create a video content site on a budget (inferring this from shared hosting), if so, take a look at this video which seems to show some tips and tricks on how to achieve this using GCP:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2OG1w6bGFo&feature=youtu.be&t=1865

Comment: GCP's Cloud CDN is part of their load balancer offering, and it's the load balancer itself that makes this path-based routing possible, not the CDN *per se*, since their CDN is essentually just a feature bit you enable on a GCP HTTP balancer.  If any of the content is not hosted inside GCP, you need reverse proxies (HAProxy, Nginx) on GCP VMs to use as balancer targets, configured to fetch that external content.  CloudFront does not have this limitation, since a CloudFront origin server can be any web server (or load balancer) that'a accessible from the Internet, whether inside AWS or not.

Comment: Astute observation